# Actionscript - Unable to trace into callback

Tags: flash, actionscript, callstack

I'm trying to get familiar with a legacy project.  In one particular function, I have the code:

```
public function update(userObj:Object):void
{
    var comm2:CommManager;
    comm2 = CommManager.getInstance();
    comm2.statusManager.employeeStatus(employeeId);
}
```

Although I can put a breakpoint that catches, I am unable to trace into either of these two lines to view the corresponding code.  In the first case, the top of the call stack reads:

```
comm::CommManager$/getInstance
```

In the next, the top of the call stack reads:

```
comm::StatusManager/employeeStatus
```

In both cases, I get a new line in the Output window:

```
Cannot display source code at this location.
```

How can I figure out where this code is coming from?  I'm not aware of any external linking, but it certainly wouldn't surprise me.

Addendum:  Although CommManager.as has a matching API, I've added corresponding breakpoints inside of it which don't catch. Also, if I rename the file, I get a compile error, telling me the CommManager type was not found. It's as if CommManager.as is only partially being used.  Although CommManager extends a class named BaseCommComponent (which extends flash.events.EventDispatcher), BaseCommComponent does not have any functions with the same name as those in CommManager.

Comment: Do you have access to `CommManager.as`?

Comment: I do have a file with that name (and similar API), however the corresponding breakpoints never hit inside of it.  Also, if I rename the file, I get a compile error, telling me the CommManager type was not found.  It's as if it's only partially being used.

Comment: I should add that CommManager extends a class named BaseCommComponent, which extends flash.events.EventDispatcher.  BaseCommComponent does not, however, have any functions with the same name as those in CommManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the code was, in fact, using an external swf.  Luckily, I had the matching fla file as well.  Going into Publish Settings and checking the "Permit Debugging" box, along with recompiling seemed to fix it.  Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.